# jquery organic tabs exceed limit

Tags: jquery, plugins, tabs

I'm using the organic tabs plugin http://css-tricks.com/4530-organic-tabs/ and I need to solve a problem.

I'm using this effect:

```
$("#tab").organicTabs().organicTabs({
                "speed": 100,
                "param": "tab"
});
```

I have two tabs like this:

```
<div id="tab">

    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-one"><a href="#one" class="current">One</a></li>
        <li class="nav-two last"><a href="#two">Two</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="list-wrap">

        <ul id="one">
            <a href="#add" id="add">Add</a><br />
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" name="birth" class="birth" /><br />
            </div>
        </ul>

        <ul id="two" class="hide">
      </ul>
     </div>   
</div> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And a jquery function to add more text fields:

```
$('#add').click(function() {

    $('<div class="input"><input type="text" name="birth" class="birth" /><br /></div>').hide().appendTo('.input').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

But as I introduce more text fields, it exceeds the size of the tab. This problem is solved by selecting the tab two and return to one. I want the tab to adjust the size as they will introduce more text fields .. is it possible?